# Wifi and ethernet problem after linux firmware update

Tags: wireless, dell

Model: Dell Vostro 15
- Current OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Upgraded from 16.04 OEM)
- Current Kernel : 4.16.3-041603-generic (updated from 4.15.03)
- **Issue:** WiFi driver disabled after the linux_firmware update.

Before doing the above-mentioned firmware update, one day got an error while booting `"ath10k_pci failed to fetch board data for..... from ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board-2.bin"`. While surfing on the net I got a solution that its a crash report of wifi driver, for that do the following solution from Dell support forum:

---

```
https://www.dell.com/support/article/in/en/inbsdt1/sln306440/killer-n1535-wireless-firmware-manual-update-guide-for-ubuntu-systems?lang=en

Linux Firmware Package

Linux-Firmware (w/ Killer N1535) Update Process

    cd ~ && mkdir linux-firmware && cd linux-firmware
    wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.176_all.deb External Link
    sudo dpkg -i *.deb
    sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci && sudo modprobe ath10k_pci

Note: To determine the current linux-firmware package available please visit: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware External Link
```

---

First I updated the Kernel from 4.15.03 to 4.16.3 (not suggested in dell forum). Then followed the forum instructions for linux_firmware update. While rebooting after the update, I got another error on booting that:

```
"ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to get boar id from otp:-1100000000/00002000 "
"ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not probe fw (-110) (First)"
```

After user login the Airplane mode is enabled and no sign of Wifi. Wired network is available and working only after reboot (every time I need to reboot the system after connecting the ethernet cable). If I press the WiFi key which is on the laptop keyboard, its only toggles between the Airplane mode and Wired network. If I turn off the Airplane mode, then it will enable the Bluetooth.

Some terminal commands results are given below:

---------------------------------------details----------------------------------

```
@Dell:~$ lshw

           *-network
                description: Network controller
                product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 31
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:129 memory:d1000000-d11fffff
```

---

```
@Dell:~$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE    SOFT      HARD
 1 bluetooth hci0   blocked unblocked
```

---

```
@Dell:~$ lspci

01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)

@Dell:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:1810]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

---

Kindly provide a solution to solve the WiFi and Ethernet issue.

-Jay